# How to set a specific timeout for each video played with Views Slideshow on Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, javascript, views

I have come accross with an issue with the view Slideshow.

I have images and videos to play on my slideshow.

However when the video plays , the slideshow just rotates before the end of the video.

As I am aware it is impossible for the slideshow to know when a video ends, I have done many researches to be able to set a dynamic timeout for each video played.

I came accross this post: https://drupal.org/node/1541254
This post describes exactly what I need to do.

However being quite new to Drupal, I have no idea where to copy and paste the given patch.

If someone could please guide me on which file in the View slideshow module I have to copy and paste that would be great.

Or even if anyone had a better solution, please share.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

welcome to this community.

I recommend you look at the [Drupal Patch Documentation (this is how to Apply a Patch, other docs go into how to create one)](https://drupal.org/patch/apply). What you're asking about is the Linux/Unix patch command when using a patchfile.

If you look at the file (from the 1st patch in the issue queue, you'll likely grab a later one). You'll see the following beginning lines:

```
diff --git a/contrib/views_slideshow_cycle/js/views_slideshow_cycle.js b/contrib/views_slideshow_cycle/js/views_slideshow_cycle.js
index 3e72ed5..c865b6d 100644
--- a/contrib/views_slideshow_cycle/js/views_slideshow_cycle.js
+++ b/contrib/views_slideshow_cycle/js/views_slideshow_cycle.js
```

This should tell you exactly what module `views_slideshow_cycle` and exactly what file `views_slideshow_cycle.js` the patchfile is a Patch for.

Comment: many thanks for your response. I think you are a life saver! Can I please ask you a last question? What are these numbers "@@ -60,6 +59,14 @@" in the middle of the code? I'm guessing I should not copy and paste those?

Comment: well you dont copy and paste a patch. You `apply` a patch and the patch program does all the work for you. Or you can figure out manually where all the `+` and `-` stuff goes in the file. Typically the `@@ stuff @@` denotes a block of changes in a file. Read the docs i linked :).

Comment: I could not thank you enough for your help on this... It's great to see Drupal has such a helpful community. I have successfuly applied these patches by following your link. I've installed Netbeans and followed the following tutorial http://www.wdtutorials.com/2012/04/08/drupal-7-how-patch-file-netbeans#.Ue56o22xvN9 . Everything works fine. Many thanks for your help!